# PDFBox 3.0.0 show complex non latin fonts

Tags: unicode, pdfbox, non-latin

I'm trying to print non-latin (Indian) text in a PDF. I'm using Lohit-Devanagari as PDType0Font but the resulting PDF puts each character as is instead of converting it to its respective complex character:

```
var sample="प्रदेश ग्रामीण व्यवसायिक";
try(var document=new PDDocument(){
    var hin=PDType0Font.load(document,
                             new File(Example.class().getResource("hindi.ttf").getFile())
    );
    var page=new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
    document.addPage(page);
    try(var stream=newPDPageContentStream(document,page)){
        var codes=hin.encode(sample);
        var strLine=new StringBuilder();
        for(var code:codes){
            if(code!=0){
                strLine.append(hin.toUnicode(code));
            }
        }
        stream.setFont(hin,10);
        stream.beginText();
        stream.newLineAtOffset(30,50);
        stream.showText(strLine.toString());
        stream.endText();
    }
    document.save("output.pdf");
}catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

The output is:
[image: output]

PDF details:

```
Lohit-Devanagari (Embedded subset)
Type: TrueType (CID)
Encoding: Identity-H
```

Comment: Complex scripts are only supported for Bengali at this time. We could make a GSUB worker for Devanagari but it won't be possible without help from people who know what this is about.

Comment: Is there any way to help?

Comment: Download the source code, search for `GsubWorkerForBengali.java` in the ZIP file, and write the same for Devanagari. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/script-development/devanagari .

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I've written `GsubWorkerforDevanagari.java`. Now what comes next?

Comment: Cool! Create a ticket in PDFBOX JIRA and attach your patch against the trunk there, or the just file. If you need to register, include some meaningful text (more than just "create an issue", e.g. mention this URL) so we know you are not a spammer. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX

Comment: @TilmanHausherr actually I haven't uploaded any subscription yet, just ironing out some code. Will upload soon.